# Is there a way to wait until Atlas Search finished indexing?

Tags: mongodb, lucene, mongodb-atlas

We're using Atlas Search and had an issues regarding readiness of the data in mongot - i.e. the insert operation returned success response, but search queries still doesn't get the updated data (sometimes it takes few seconds).
Is there a way that Mongo will let us know when the index operation finished completely (including indexing)?

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it, but it seems you can query this data from the Atlas api: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/api/fts-indexes-get-all/

Base URL: `https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0`

```
GET /groups/{GROUP-ID}/clusters/{CLUSTER-NAME}/fts/indexes/{DATABASE-NAME}/{COLLECTION-NAME}
```

Each index has a `status` property which is documented as follows:

> Status of the index. Value can be one of the following statuses:
>
> IN_PROGRESS - Atlas is building or re-building the index after an
> edit.
>
> STEADY - Index is ready to use.
>
> FAILED - Atlas could not build the index.
>
> MIGRATING - Atlas cluster tier is being upgraded and indexes are
> migrating.